# image not showing when preview from html/css

Tags: css, html

I have got a problem my css wont load my last two images

```
top-row background-image: url(../images/top-bg.png) top left repeat-x; width:100%;

top-bg background-image: url(../images/top-row-bg.png) top center no-repeat; width:100%;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
```

use this

```
background-image: #000 url(myBackground.jpg) center center fixed no-repeat;
```

for firefox

```
-moz-background-image: #000 url(myBackground.jpg) center center fixed no-repeat;
```

for safari or chrome

```
-webkit-background-image: #000 url(myBackground.jpg) center center fixed no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes:

- Your CSS rule seems incorrect. It should be prefixed with a dot because otherwise it assumes that you have a DOM element called `<top-row>` and `<top-bg>` which is very unlikely
- The image location that you specify in the url must be relative to the location of the CSS file.

So:

```
.top-row {
    background-image: url(../images/top-bg.png) top left repeat-x;
    width:100%;
}

.top-bg {
    background-image: url(../images/top-row-bg.png) top center no-repeat;
    width:100%;
}
```

For example if this CSS is located in `/styles/main.css` the images must be located in `/images/top-bg.png` and `/images/top-row-bg.png`. Ensure that this is the case.

Also I would very strongly recommend you using a debugging tool such as FireBug or Chrome Developer Toolbar which allows you to inspect the DOM and the exact CSS rules that are being applied to the elements. It also allows you to inspect the network traffic and if you make some errors while referencing your static resources you will get 404 errors.